# Addon.d script on Android 11

Tags: scripts, android-11

Google introduced [`system_ext` partition in Android 11](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions#changes-in-android-r) which can use `system` resources and can include system modules that:

> - *Extend AOSP system modules in the `system` partition*. We recommend upstreaming such modules to AOSP so they can be installed to the `system` partition later.
> - *Bundle OEM or SoC-specific modules*. We recommend unbundling such modules so they can be installed to the `product` or `vendor` partition.

I want to remove 2 folders named Snap and Gallery2 from `/system_ext/priv-app` partition. So, I created `addon.d` survival script to remove automatically every time I dirty flash a ROM.

The scripts commands are-

```
#!/sbin/sh
rm -rf "system_ext/priv-app/Gallery2"
rm -rf "system_ext/priv-app/Snap"
```

But the script is not working. Every time I dirty flash a ROM, I have to remove those folders manually.

Comment: *echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S'): $0 started" >> /cache/addon.log*

Comment: create some log via your script to confirm your script is executed at all. beware partition has to be mounted

Comment: also you should use absolute paths (leading / )